# Between Expand and TrigExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, trigonometry

Consider a simple trigonometric expression below :

```
(cos(x)+2)^6+(sin(y)+1)^4
```

Now following outputs were obtained from Mathematica 10

```
Expand[((1 + Sin[y])^2)^2 + ((2 + Cos[x])^3)^2]

65 + 192 Cos[x] + 240 Cos[x]^2 + 160 Cos[x]^3 + 60 Cos[x]^4 + 
 12 Cos[x]^5 + Cos[x]^6 + 4 Sin[y] + 6 Sin[y]^2 + 4 Sin[y]^3 + 
 Sin[y]^4
```

Hence, as expected [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html) multiplied out the products and positive integral powers in the highest level of the expression giving the above result.

However

```
TrigExpand[((1 + Sin[y])^2)^2 + ((2 + Cos[x])^3)^2]

3379/16 + (639 Cos[x])/2 + (4815 Cos[x]^2)/32 + (175 Cos[x]^3)/4 + (
 123 Cos[x]^4)/16 + (3 Cos[x]^5)/4 + Cos[x]^6/32 - (7 Cos[y]^2)/2 + 
 Cos[y]^4/8 - (4815 Sin[x]^2)/32 - 525/4 Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 - 
 369/8 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^2 - 15/2 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2 - 
 15/32 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x]^2 + (123 Sin[x]^4)/16 + 15/4 Cos[x] Sin[x]^4 + 
 15/32 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^4 - Sin[x]^6/32 + 7 Sin[y] - 
 3 Cos[y]^2 Sin[y] + (7 Sin[y]^2)/2 - 3/4 Cos[y]^2 Sin[y]^2 + 
 Sin[y]^3 + Sin[y]^4/8
```

Mathematica documentation states the following about TrigExpand :

> TrigExpand splits up sums and integer multiples that appear in arguments of trigonometric functions, and then expands out products of trigonometric functions into sums of powers, using trigonometric identities when possible.

However

1. There were no products of trigonometric functions in the input above.
2. The final output contains products of trigonometric functions.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Try `Simplify` on `TrigExpand` and see what happens.

Comment: 1/32 (6758 + 10224 Cos[x] + 4815 Cos[2 x] + 1400 Cos[3 x] + 
   246 Cos[4 x] + 24 Cos[5 x] + Cos[6 x] - 112 Cos[2 y] + 
   4 Cos[4 y] + 224 Sin[y] - 32 Sin[3 y])

FullSimplify returns the same result as Simplify

Comment: Now note that in the first expression (the one with only `Expand`) you have **powers** of trigs, e.g. `Cos[x]^6`. In the second (`TrigExpand`), after `Simplyfy`ing it, there are **harmonics**, e.g. `Cos[6 x]`. So, `TrigExpand` does exactly what the docs say. Consider also a simpler example: `Expand[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2]` and `TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2]`, as well as the first two examples for `Simplify` in the docs.

Comment: When `TrigExpand` encounters the input expression, and expands the exponents, it should see the output which `Expand` gives. At that moment there are no multiple angles (e.g  `6x`) in the argument of the trigonometric functions. So, ideally shouldn't it stop there ? What does it innovate to bring about a harmonic representation ? This begs the question, that does `TrigExpand` try to use identities to force a harmonic representation of an expression before producing the expansion and giving the final result ? Unfortunately, these intricacies are mentioned nowhere in my knowledge.

Comment: From your own post: "using trigonometric identities when possible".Simplifying, `Expand` works on polynomials, `TrigExpnd` uses trig properties. One can make `Expand` work on trigs by adding `Trig -> True` (also from the docs).

Comment: Okay. I take that as an answer. I believe however that it could have been explained by the documentation in a better way (rather than a mere 3 lines !!).  It is very weird that a function will forcefully modify an expression to suit its application. Even Mathematica Guidebook on Programming does not touch these details. 
If your comment could have been written as an answer, I would have most certainly accepted them as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's name the two possibilities:

```
a = Expand[((1 + Sin[y])^2)^2 + ((2 + Cos[x])^3)^2]
```

> 65 + 192 Cos[x] + 240 Cos[x]^2 + 160 Cos[x]^3 + 60 Cos[x]^4 + 
>    12 Cos[x]^5 + Cos[x]^6 + 4 Sin[y] + 6 Sin[y]^2 + 4 Sin[y]^3 + 
>    Sin[y]^4

```
b = TrigExpand[((1 + Sin[y])^2)^2 + ((2 + Cos[x])^3)^2]
```

> 3379/16 + (639 Cos[x])/2 + (4815 Cos[x]^2)/32 + (175 Cos[x]^3)/4 + (
>    123 Cos[x]^4)/16 + (3 Cos[x]^5)/4 + Cos[x]^6/32 - (7 Cos[y]^2)/2 + 
>    Cos[y]^4/8 - (4815 Sin[x]^2)/32 - 525/4 Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 - 
>    369/8 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^2 - 15/2 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2 - 
>    15/32 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x]^2 + (123 Sin[x]^4)/16 + 15/4 Cos[x] Sin[x]^4 + 
>    15/32 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^4 - Sin[x]^6/32 + 7 Sin[y] - 
>    3 Cos[y]^2 Sin[y] + (7 Sin[y]^2)/2 - 3/4 Cos[y]^2 Sin[y]^2 + 
>    Sin[y]^3 + Sin[y]^4/8

`b` has a rather unappealing form, so let's `Simplify` it:

```
Simplify@b
```

> 1/32 (6758 + 10224 Cos[x] + 4815 Cos[2 x] + 1400 Cos[3 x] + 
>      246 Cos[4 x] + 24 Cos[5 x] + Cos[6 x] - 112 Cos[2 y] + 
>      4 Cos[4 y] + 224 Sin[y] - 32 Sin[3 y])

Note that `a` contains only **powers**, e.g. `Cos[x]^6` of trigonometric functions (trigs for short). That is consistent with what `Expand` does, being in most cases working on polynomial or polynomial-type expressions. On the other hand, `b` contains **harmonics**, e.g. `Cos[6 x]`. This is also consistent with the documentation, which states

> `TrigExpand` splits up sums and integer multiples that appear in arguments of trigonometric functions, and then expands out products of trigonometric functions into sums of powers, **using trigonometric identities when possible**.

This is well illustrated with a very simple example:

```
Expand[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2]
```

> Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x]^2

```
TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2]
```

> 1

One can make `Expand` work on trigs in a way `TrigExpand` does by adding `Trig -> True`, i.e.

```
Expand[((1 + Sin[y])^2)^2 + ((2 + Cos[x])^3)^2, Trig -> True]
```